# Add Custom HTML ID to Rails Select Box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Usually, adding an ID tag at the end of a rails form helper, does the trick. However, this does not seem to be working for select boxes. What am I doing wrong?

```
<%= form_for(@song) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :category, [['Pop', 1], ['Rap', 2]] , :id=>"choose-category"%>
<% end %>
```

^The ID is not getting set here properly, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) method takes four arguments, `html_options` is the fourth, therefore you have to pass an empty hash as the third parameter (`options`):

```
f.select(:category, [['Pop', 1], ['Rap', 2]], {}, :id => "choose-category")
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, I remember skimming through the docs, and noticing that four arguments were needed, but never really realized that I only had three, nor knew how to add a default argument. Thank you very much @toro2k

Comment: @toro2k shouldn't it be `id: "choose-catgory"` for Rails 3.x+ and ruby 1.9.x+ to work to the current standards?

Comment: @RyanMacG `{id: "foo"}` and `{:id => "foo"}` are equivalent in Ruby 1.9+.

Comment: @toro2k I know, I was just under the impression that `id: "foo"` was the more acceptable solution. I might be entirely wrong I was just curious

Comment: @toro2k thanks for clearing that up, I hadn't seen the styleguide you linked to before.